# Android JUnit tests not detecting in Robotium

Tags: android, junit, robotium, junit3

I am trying to run following Android JUnit3 test with robotium:

```
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import com.package.sample.MyActivityClass;
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

public class TestSample extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivityClass> {
    private Solo solo;
    public TestSample() {
        super("com.package.sample", MyActivityClass.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    public void clickbutton1() throws Exception{
        solo.clickOnButton("abc");
        solo.setActivityOrientation(Solo.LANDSCAPE);
        assertTrue(solo.searchText("load"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception{
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }
}
```

The JUnit explores shows 0/0 tests runs. The debugger does not hit any code path mentioned here and Console outputs "test run finished"??:

```
Uploading MyAppTest.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
Installing MyAppTest.apk...
Success!
Project dependency found, installing: MyApp
Uploading MyApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
Installing MyApp.apk...
Success!
Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on device emulator-5554
Collecting test information
Sending test information to Eclipse
Running tests...
Test run finished
```

Does anyone has an idea what is wrong? I have followed all steps in robotium tutorials religiously. I know there have been many questions around this but I have take care of all answers.

Also Robotium has similar problem with JUnit4 [here](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/issues/detail?id=268).

Comment: I am using Android 2.3.3 [API 10], Junit3, Robotium 3.2.1

Comment: Got the issue. Junit3 for some stupid reason( stupid as its not clearly mentioned in doc) expects testcase name to include "test*" prefix.

Comment: It took me DAYS to figure that out. I actually had to contact the guy who created it to figure that out. You would think that they would mention that in their documentation, but they don't.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I know what is wrong.

In order to run your tests, you need to begin them with `test`. So your code should be like this:

```
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import com.package.sample.MyActivityClass;
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

public class TestSample extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivityClass> {
    private Solo solo;
    public TestSample() {
        super("com.package.sample", MyActivityClass.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    //the test methods MUST begin with test...
    public void testClickbutton1() throws Exception{
        solo.clickOnButton("abc");
        solo.setActivityOrientation(Solo.LANDSCAPE);
        assertTrue(solo.searchText("load"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception{
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }
}
```

I had a similar issue awhile ago, and Robotium doesn't have the greatest documentation. I hope this helps you out :)

Comment: +1 for the great help.But there is another problem with me, 
Eclipse give me error like : `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo
at com.MAT.CanadaImmigrationApp.test.SettingTest.setUp(SettingTest.java:19)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)
`

Comment: please check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846555/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-jayway-android-robotium-solo-solo

Comment: please Help me for the the above problem,Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming that you figured it out, as the question you posted has been deleted?

Answer (score 1):

I did everything what you said, but I still got error with 0/0 test.I had found the solution, which is related to constructors:

```
// I DELETED THIS CONSTRUCTOR
public TestHomeScreenTest(String pkg, Class<ScreenSlidePagerActivity> activityClass) {
    super(pkg, activityClass);
}


//GOOD SOLUTION:    
public TestHomeScreenTest() {
    super("com.dolphin.homescreen", ScreenSlidePagerActivity.class);
}
```

and it now WOOORKS ! :)